# is it possible to implement multiple wcf services( multiple http: scheme)

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to implement multiple services with the same scheme HTTP?

Like this:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyServiceBecouseError.MyNameService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="xxx" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyServiceBecouseError.IMyNameService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="yyy" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyServiceBecouseError.IMyNameServiceSecond"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/eff-off"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5555/eff-off"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
As a result you'll have your two services listening at:

- http://localhost:8080/eff-off/xxx
- http://localhost:8080/eff-off/yyy
- http://localhost:5555/eff-off/xxx
- http://localhost:5555/eff-off/yyy

And of course metadata exchange endpoints will be there as well.